jOOQ blocking in `DSL.using`
Some of my Java services have started "freezing" at startup (intermittently, restarting them makes them work). I used AWS CodeGuru to see what they were executing while they were "doing nothing" and I saw that 2 of my threads where using 68% of the CPU, inside of the DSL.using method (the other thread was blocked).
Here is one such threads:

The method that executed DSL.using looks like this:
    public void myMethod(final Instant now) {
        final int count = using(configuration)
                .update(MY_TABLE)
                .set(MY_TABLE.ACTIVE, true)
                .where(MY_TABLE.PAUSED_UNTIL.isNotNull())
                .and(MY_TABLE.ACTIVE.isFalse())
                .execute();
        if (count > 0) {
            ...
        }
    }

Where configuration is derived like this (on the constructor of this class):
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceFactory.provide()
    Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
                .derive(dataSource)
                .derive(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
                .derive(EnumFixingExecuteListener::new);

And DataSourceFactory is our own class, and the provide method is this:
    public HikariDataSource provide() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", postgresConfig.host);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(6);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", postgresConfig.database);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", postgresConfig.username);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", postgresConfig.password);

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        log.trace("Providing dataSource {}", dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

Do you know why could DSL.using be freezing? or what else can cause it to appear frozen?
Versions used:

jOOQ 3.16.23 (Build date: 2023-12-20T14:13:48Z)
PostgreSQL 14.10


That looks like a class initialisation deadlock between two processes. I'm not sure what would cause it from your description, but a simple workaround seems to be to eagerly load those classes long before your actual MyJobDao logic is invoked.

Thank you @LukasEder I did a code change to initialise the DAO earlier on and I'll see if the issue reproduces (it had been happening like once every 2 weeks).

@LukasEder Initializing the DAO earlier didn't work. But we traced the deadlock to this static initializer in DefaultDSLContext. We tested one of the workarounds proposed in  issue 3777 and it is working so far: Class.forName("org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType") in the main thread. So far so good, I'll give it some more days to be sure this worked in every case.

TL;DR
To workaround this, I used one of the solutions proposed in this GH issue:
try {
    Class.forName("org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

Explanation
Using a thread dump we found the deadlock happened in this line of jOOQ's DefaultDSLContext:
static {
    // Load all dialect-specific data types
    // TODO [#650] Make this more reliable using a data type registry

    try {
        Class.forName(SQLDataType.class.getName());
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
}

And we found jOOQ issue 3777, where it's explained how to reproduce it (link) by having a thread reference a specialized DB data type and in another thread, the SQLDataType class:
Thread th1 = new Thread(() -> SQLDataType.VARCHAR(6));
Thread th2 = new Thread(() -> PostgresDataType.VARCHAR.length(6));

I looked through my code where was I using SQLDataType, and found out this code:
private static final Field<String[]> myField = field("MY_FIELD", String[].class);

internally invokes a deprecated method:
@Deprecated(forRemoval = true, since = "3.11")
@NotNull
@Support
public static <T> DataType<T> getDataType(Class<T> type) {
    return DefaultDataType.getDataType(SQLDialect.DEFAULT, type);
}

The solution at the beginning of this SO answer has been working for some time now, I'll update this answer in case the workaround didn't work.
I imagine I can change String[].class in my fields declarations by something to avoid the issue, but this code pattern is quite extended in our source code, so that would take a lot of time and effort.
